# How to find out the version of cygwin setup-x86.exe?

Tags: cygwin

I wonder how to find out the version of the cygwin setup program (setup-x86 or setup-x86_64). I know there's setup.ini file when the setup program downloads stuff. There's a line "setup_version: 2.XXX" therein. Is there any direct way to get the version number? Something akin to "setup --version" on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no version command line as you can see from the help output

```
/setup-x86.exe -h
```

You can ask on the mailing list for this additional info to be added
as setup is currently under deep review.

The only way, currently available, is to look at the start window

[image: Cygwin Setup start window]

Comment: So there's no other way to get the version unless a human runs the setup program. My script now downloads the setup every time it does a quiet update to ensure the setup program is the latest. Kinda wasteful when the setup program doesn't get frequent upgrades.

Comment: you can download the signature from `https://cygwin.com/install.html`. It is much smaller than setup and if it is not changed also the program is not changed.

Comment: Additionally, if your script uses `wget` to download the setup program, you can use the `-N` flag to check the timestamp, and it won't download if it hasn't been updated.

Comment: @Pak, thanks for the `wget -N` tip. I am using a PowerShell snippet to mimic wget. To enable '-N' in PowerShell is more work than I can manage at the moment. But good to know!