# What is the file named "setup.zst.sig" during installation?

Tags: cygwin

I note that when cygwin's setup.exe installs packages now, it looks for a file named "setup.zst.sig" first. What's the content and format of this binary file? How to produce a valid "setup.zst.sig"?

This must have been a recent change. Previously it looked for "setup.exe.sig" first. I use the feature (to detect whether "setup.exe.sig" changed) to decide whether my cygwin installation needs to be updated. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676658/how-to-find-out-the-version-of-cygwin-setup-x86-exe) for an application example.

EDIT: @matzeri:

[image: This is the error message on screen.[1]]

Comment: It is probably the SHA256 hash signature of the file `setup.zst`. It is used to check that it was downloaded without errors (or MiTM versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup.zst.sig is not yet used. 
The "zst" functionality was introduced in the program to eventually replace the 
previous compression methods of setup.ini and the packages

```
const std::string setup_exts[] = { "zst", "xz", "bz2", "ini" };
```

For checking the update of setup-ARCH.exe you need to use the standard signature.

```
https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe.sig 
https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe.sig
```

The pop up you shows seems to happen only on FTP mirror server, the HTTP servers
do not produce it.

It is clearly a bug in setup
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2019-02/msg00153.html

Comment: Yes, I do use the setup-ARCH.exe.sig to determine whether to update. However, the absence of setup.zst.sig leads to a pesky error message from setup.exe. So I am thinking of producing a valid (even empty) setup.zst.sig to circumvent that.

Comment: The error message: 550 /cygwin/ARCH/setup.zst.sig No such file or directory

Comment: It should be 404 and only visible on the  `/var/log/setup.log`. Are you installing from local disk or what ?

Comment: I have edited the original question to include a screenshot. I have tried to insert an empty setup.zst.sig in the directory where packages are downloaded but the error message still appears. I did check /var/log/setup.log which says "mbox Internet Error: 550 /cygwin/x86_64/setup.zst.sig: No such file or directory
mbox Internet Error: 550 /cygwin/x86_64/setup.zst: No such file or directory"

Comment: It seems specific of using a FTP mirror. With HTTP mirror  there is no pop up and only a log of 404 error

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the .sig files carry a SHA-512 hash of the respective file without that extension, signed with the private key available only to Cygwin the company.

https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.install-security